# How to call a stored procedure in SQL developer where the argument is a long string with carriage returns

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to run a stored procedure that takes a string with carriage returns as an argument from within a SQL Developer session. Specifically the string is itself a SQL statement which gets picked up by the procedure, processed and stored in a table.

The problem is finding a way to preserve the readable formatting of the statements i.e., text with multiple lines / carriage returns. The closest I have gotten is the following:

1) Create a new table to store the SQL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE sql_table
(
    id NUMBER,
    sql_string  CLOB
);
```

2) Create a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
   update_sql(var_id NUMBER, var_sql_string IN CLOB) IS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sql_table (id, sql_string) VALUES (var_id, var_sql_string);
    --do other stuff
END; /
```

3) Run the following command to add a new row with a sql statement to the table:

```
EXEC update_sql(127,'&input');
```

4) At the prompt, paste in a multiple line statement such as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM any_table
WHERE a = b;
```

5) Then query sql_table and copy and paste the content of the column sql_string into a text editor - the carriage returns are now gone:

```
SELECT * FROM any_table WHERE a=b;
```

As mentioned, I would like to preserve the carriage returns so that the statements display nicely when extracted from the table.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share any sample text you wanted to store, so I made up a very simple one

```
DECLARE
  VAR_ID NUMBER;
  VAR_SQL_STRING CLOB;
BEGIN
  VAR_ID := 4;
  VAR_SQL_STRING := q'[SELECT
  * FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'JEFF']';

  UPDATE_SQL(
    VAR_ID => VAR_ID,
    VAR_SQL_STRING => VAR_SQL_STRING
  );
--rollback; 
END;
```

The [q feature for string literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617) is quite nice because it handles quoted strings for you auto-magically, which you'll have all over the place in your SQL. Steven Feuerstein talks about this [here in his article covering strings in PL/SQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-strings).

You don't say HOW you're extracting the data...

> As mentioned, I would like to preserve the carriage returns so that
>   the statements display nicely when extracted from the table.

But browsing the table in SQL Developer -

[image]